# keyboard EventListener in javascript

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events, keydown, keyevent

can anyone explain me how the argument e is captured and passed as a function callback which displays the keyboardEvent Object in console.
Same this can be acheived by using

```
() => console.log(event);
```

so why do we do like this

```
 (e) => console.log(e);
```

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
console.log("key Pressed");
console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: I don't get what you mean by the first part of the question, but `console.log();` displays it's arguments in the console, and you have that inside your listener code with the object `e` displaying itself. `e => {}` is short-hand for `function e() {}`. So, `e` is a function which displays itself after being converted to a `KeyboardEvent` via `addEventListener`

Comment: no, he means that you can access `event` without passing it to the callback function... its just there and he asks why is that

Comment: lfaruki, that exactly what i ask for! Why do we need to pass argument to callback function when we can retrive it by using console.log(event)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Event *object*** exists in ***Spyglass*** based browsers but doesn't exist in ***Mosaic*** based browsers as a scriptable object, or at least as an accessible object.

For this reason ***Mosaic*** (which was killed by The Project "Mosaic Killa"), from where we now have ***Mozilla*** for short, which in that process developed *Netscape Navigator*, had to arbitrarily pass the *event object* as a *value* of a function *argument*.

So, in order to be compatible with both worlds, the arbitrary event assignment to the first provided function argument has become mandatory for both.

Although you can still call for the event object in the *Spyglass* line of browsers, if that's your exclusive target clientele on some intranet app.